# Tumblr pages no longer redirect - How to redirect using pages on a Tumblr blog

Tags: tumblr

It used to be that you could create Tumblr pages to redirect to posts or other non-Tumblr URLs. For example, you could create a page `pets` and redirect it to a post on your blog (using the post's relative URL such as `/345879345843/look-at-my-cute-pets`) such that visiting `my-blog.tumblr.com/pets` would automatically redirect you to `my-blog.tumblr.com/345879345843/look-at-my-cute-pets`.

However, since April or May 2019 at least, it seems you can still create pages, but you can't use them to redirect to other URLs. You can put content on the pages but they can't redirect anymore. Old pages that were already set to redirect continue to do so, but no *new* redirect pages can be created.

Is there still a way to create Tumblr pages to redirect?